# On $\int_1^\infty \left(\sum_{1\leq k\leq t}\frac{\mu(k)}{k}\right)\log \left(\frac{1-e^{\frac{2\pi i}{t}}}{1-e^{\frac{-2\pi i}{t}}}\right)dt$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, convergence-divergence, analytic-number-theory, mobius-function

I've deduced the following, but I don't know if it is right

> **Claim.** One has that 
>   $$\frac{1}{\zeta(3)}=\frac{6}{\pi^2}-\frac{i}{\pi}\int_1^\infty m(t)\log \left(\frac{1-e^{\frac{2\pi i}{t}}}{1-e^{\frac{-2\pi i}{t}}}\right)dt,\tag{1}$$ where for real numbers $x\geq 1$ one has $m(x)=\sum_{1\leq k\leq x}\frac{\mu(k)}{k}$, being $\mu(n)$ the Möbius function.

Notice that I am not saying that it is interesting because from the problem to compute $(\zeta(3))^{-1}$ I am trying to study a more difficult thing, that is the integral in RHS of $(1)$. Since my proof had steps that maybe are wrongs, and since I am not able to compute an approximation of the integral using a CAS I am asking

> **Question.** Q1.) Was right the formula $(1)$? Add the reasoning of why no, or well if the Claim is true and you want add calculations/reasonings as companion of mine. Q2.) Is it possible to get an approximation of such integral in RHS of $(1)$ (I presume thus that is convergent; and notice that is a complex number) without using my identity itself? **Thanks in advance.**

Skecht of my proof, as I said I don't provide the justifications:

*Step 1.* From the specialization $x=1/k$ in the Fourier series for $x(1-x)$ I wrote $$ \frac{1}{k} \left( 1-\frac{1}{k} \right)  =\frac{1}{6} -\frac{1}{\pi^2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1 }{n^2}\cos \left( \frac{2\pi n}{k} \right),\tag{2}$$ multiplying by $\frac{\mu(k)}{k}$, taking the sum $\sum_{k=1}^\infty$, and invoking the prime number theorem and particular values of Dirichlet series, one has
$$ \frac{1}{\zeta(3)} =\frac{6}{\pi^2}+ \frac{1}{\pi^2}\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(k)}{k}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1 }{n^2}\cos \left( \frac{2\pi n}{k} \right).\tag{3}$$

*Step 2.* From $(3)$ and this deduction of  Abel's identity (I've used the prime number theorem) $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\sum_{k\leq x}\frac{\mu(k)}{k}\cos \left( \frac{2\pi n}{k} \right)=0-2\pi n\lim_{x\to\infty}\int_1^x \left(\sum_{k\leq t}\frac{\mu(k)}{k}\right)\sin \left( \frac{2\pi n}{t} \right)\frac{dt}{t^2},\tag{4}$$ one has the Claim using the closed-form for $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}\sin\left( \frac{2\pi n}{t} \right)$$ that provide us [Wolfram Alpha online calculator](https://www.wolframalpha.com/) with this code

`sum 1/n sin(2 pi n/t), from n=1 to infinity`

I presume that this last calculation is using geometric series.$\square$

---

As is implicit I am not sure if my reasonings, justifications were 100% rights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question seems very interesting.are you trying to reprove the fact $\zeta(3)$ is a irrational number?may be you can  comment under this answer to give me more information.
In my opinion,the process of you to get the formula 1 is merely true with some typos more or less anyway.So I will focus on:

- Q2:Is it possible to get an approximation of such integral in RHS of
  $\frac{1}{\zeta(3)}=\frac{6}{\pi^2}-\frac{i}{\pi}\int_1^\infty m(t)\log \left(\frac{1-e^{\frac{2\pi i}{t}}}{1-e^{\frac{-2\pi i}{t}}}\right)dt,\tag{1}$,where for real numbers $x\geq 1$ ,one has $m(x)=\sum_{1≤k≤x}\frac{\mu(k)}{k}$ ,being $\mu(n)$ the Möbius function.

At first I want to point out $M(x)=\sum_{1≤k≤x}\mu(k)=o(X)$ is equivalent to $m(x)=\sum_{1≤k≤x}\frac{\mu(k)}{k}=o(1)$ is equivalent to the prime number theorem.the later equivalent is proved by Laudou in 1906,this first equivalent is just to investigate the function $\theta(x)=\{\frac{N}{x}\}$.

By the abel sum formula we can rewrite the RHS of (1) in the form:$\sum_{1\leq k\leq {\infty}}\mu(k)f(k)$ In analytic number theory we will deal with a lot of series in the form:$\sum_{1\leq k\leq x}\mu(k)f(k)$,this can be view as the correlation of sequences $\{\mu(n)\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ and $\{f(n)\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$.circle method or a advance version,so called $\delta$ method to provide approximation like this kind of thing but a continued version.in the discrete version I think the powerful tool may be the Bourgain-Sarnak-Ziegler theorem:

Theorem(B-S-Z). Let $F : N \to C$ with $|F| \leq 1$ and let ν be a multiplicative function with |ν| ≤ 1. Let τ > 0 be a small parameter and assume that for all primes $p_1, p_2 ≤ e^{1/τ}$ , $p_\neq p_2$, we have that for $M$ large enough

$|\sum_{m\leq M}  F(p_1m)\overline {F(p_2m)}|  ≤ τM$.

Then for N large enough

$|\sum_{m\leq M} ν(n)F(n) | ≤ 2 \sqrt{τ log1/τ}M$.

this theorem is not difficult to prove by bilinear method and Cauchy-Schwarz,you can see the detail in https://arxiv.org/abs/1110.0992v1.
According to this theorem,to get a good approximation of $\sum_{1\leq k\leq x}\mu(k)f(k)$ we use need a good approximation on $\sum_{1\leq k\leq x}f(p_1x)\overline {f(p_2x)}$.this will be much easier.but for the RHS $f(x)$ is very complicated so I do not have a non-trivial estimate for $\sum_{1\leq k\leq x}f(p_1x)\overline {f(p_2x)}$ until now.

I hope this may help you.

Comment: corrected,thanks.

Comment: $\sum_{k \le x} \mu(k) f(k)=O(x)$ doesn't seem like a good approximation

Comment: @reuns,sorry,it is $\sum_{k\leq x}\mu(k)f(k)=o(x)$,when $f(k)=1,\forall k$,this is equivalent to the prime theorem.By the way I learn this from https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/08/30/an-elementary-inequality-involving-the-mobius-function/#comment-488106.

Comment: Sure $\sum_{k \le x} \mu(k) = o(x)$ is equivalent to the PNT but we expect it to be $\mathcal{O}(x^{1/2}\log x)$ (Riemann hypothesis)

Comment: yeah,but it seems unlikely could be proved until now,maybe the moment estimate of Health-Brown have some potential to attack RH.By the way on hyperbolic surface very recent there is some progress on the zeros distribution of zeta function near the critical line,see https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.02909.In my opinion this work is very similar to the finite field case of RH.

Comment: Many thanks for your contribution. I am going to need some hours to read it. I am agree that maybe there are typos.

Comment: I am familiar with Bourgain's article because it is in a core position of the canonical approach to Sarnak conjecture. If you meet some trouble in read the article I am pleasure to help you.

Comment: Many thanks for your help, but currently I am an aficionado without abilites to read the paper. I hope that in the future I improve my skills in mathematics. Any case many thanks. On the other hand if you want to study yourself ideas on some of my questions in this site, feel free to do it. Isn't required a response of this comment, good week.